# Long delay when calling swapCursor in OnLoadFinished

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-cursoradapter, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I am implementing a ListView that contains a Customized CursorAdpater with a LoaderCallbacks. When OnCreatLoader is called I am running an AsyncTaskLoader that gets theCursor from the DB. I noticed that there is a delay when calling swapCursor after the cursor is loaded. Is there any solution for this like loading 10 items at a time?If so, Where can I do this?

```
    @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
{
    // Create the Cursor that will take care of the data being displayed
    Log.d("TAG", "onCreateLoader...");
    return new MessageAsyncTaskLoader(getActivity());

}


    @Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor)
{
    // Now Bind the data to the View
    Log.d("TAG", "onLoadFinished...ARG1= " + cursor);
    mCusrorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);// This is were the delay is...
}

    public static class MessageAsyncTaskLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor>
{
    Cursor cursor;
public MessageAsyncTaskLoader(Context context)
{
    super(context); 
}

@Override
    protected void onStartLoading()
    {
        super.onStartLoading();
        mCusrorAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(mContext);
        mListView.setAdapter(mCusrorAdapter);
        forceLoad();
    }

@Override
public Cursor loadInBackground()
{
     cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null,null,
            DataBase.COLUMN_MESSAGE_DATE+ " DESC");
    return cursor;
}

@Override
    protected void onStopLoading()
    {
        super.onStopLoading();
        cursor.close();
    }

}
```